# ListView selecionando posição

Tags: android, listview, retrofit, posicionamento

Tenho um código que preciso que ele selecione o item por sua posição...
No caso ele já está selecionando mas ele seleciona aleatoriamente.

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, long l) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuscaActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Deseja inserir na lista?");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        TextView codigointerno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codigointerno);
        String interno = codigointerno.getText().toString();
        TextView codigoean = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.codigo_ean);
        String ean = codigoean.getText().toString();
        ListaProduto produto = new ListaProduto();
        produto.setCodigoproduto(interno);
        produto.setCodigoean(ean);
        produto.setUclogin(getSharedPreferences(PREFS_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("PrefUser", ""));
        loadJsonLista(produto);
      }
    });



    public class ListaAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Produto> {
private Context context;
private List<Produto> values;

public ListaAdapter(Context context, List<Produto> values) {
    super(context, R.layout.lista_item, values);

    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
                (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista_item, parent, false);
    }
    TextView interno = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.codigointerno);
    TextView ean = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.codigo_ean);
    TextView completa = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.descricao_completa);
    TextView reduzida = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.descricao_reduzida);

    Produto item = values.get(position);

    String message_interno = item.getCodigointerno();
    String message_ean = item.getCodigoean();
    String message_completa = item.getDescricaocompleta();
    String message_reduzida = item.getDescricaoreduzida();

    interno.setText(message_interno);
    ean.setText(message_ean);
    completa.setText(message_completa);
    reduzida.setText(message_reduzida);

    return row;
}
```

}

```
          public class ListaProduto implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2161110911377686463L;

@SerializedName("uclogin")
String uclogin;

@SerializedName("codigoproduto")
String codigoproduto;

@SerializedName("codigoean")
String codigoean;

public String getUclogin() {
    return uclogin;
}

public void setUclogin(String uclogin) {
    this.uclogin = uclogin;
}

public String getCodigoproduto() {
    return codigoproduto;
}

public void setCodigoproduto(String codigoproduto) {
    this.codigoproduto = codigoproduto;
}

public String getCodigoean() {
    return codigoean;
}

public void setCodigoean(String codigoean) {
    this.codigoean = codigoean;
}
```

}

```
            public class Produto {
 public String codigointerno;
public String codigoean;
public String descricaocompleta;
private String descricaoreduzida;
private double precovenda;
private double precocusto;
private double estoque;
private double margem;


public String getCodigointerno() {
    return codigointerno;
}

public void setCodigointerno(String codigointerno) {
    this.codigointerno = codigointerno;
}

public String getCodigoean() {
    return codigoean;
}

public void setCodigoean(String codigoean) {
    this.codigoean = codigoean;
}

public String getDescricaocompleta() {
    return descricaocompleta;
}

public void setDescricaocompleta(String descricaocompleta) {
    this.descricaocompleta = descricaocompleta;
}

public String getDescricaoreduzida() {
    return descricaoreduzida;
}

public void setDescricaoreduzida(String descricaoreduzida) {
    this.descricaoreduzida = descricaoreduzida;
}

public double getPrecovenda() {
    return precovenda;
}

public void setPrecovenda(double precovenda) {
    this.precovenda = precovenda;
}

public double getPrecocusto() {
    return precocusto;
}

public void setPrecocusto(double precocusto) {
    this.precocusto = precocusto;
}

public double getEstoque() {
    return estoque;
}

public void setEstoque(double estoque) {
    this.estoque = estoque;
}

public double getMargem() {
    return margem;
}

public void setMargem(double margem) {
    this.margem = margem;
}
```

}

```
           public void loadJsonLista(ListaProduto produto){

    Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://"+getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("PrefHost", "") +":8080/FazendaWebservice/webresources/fazenda/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    Retrofit retrofit = builder.build();

    ListaProdutosClient client = retrofit.create(ListaProdutosClient.class);
    Call<ListaProduto> call = client.reposForUser(produto);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ListaProduto>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ListaProduto> call, Response<ListaProduto> response) {
                ListaProduto produtos = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Código: " + produtos.getCodigoproduto(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ListaProduto> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(BuscaActivity.this, "Erro ao criar lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você criou uma array list certo ? você precisa pegar a posição atual na arraylist que está sendo populada, assim você consegue os dados que precisa, ficaria mais ou menos assim, quando você for instanciar a classe pode fazer desta maneira:

```
ListaProduto produto = arrayList.get(position);
```

Dessa forma você recupera os dados de acordo com a position na chamada do método

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> adapterView, final View view, final int position, long l)
```

Como instanciei meu adapter:

```
adapter = new MinhaClasseAdapter(AtualActivity.this, arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Cara estou usando retrofit, não usei arraylist, usei apenas um adapter.

Comment: Como você instanciou seu adapter ? Se você estivesse usando arrayList você colocaria ela como segundo parametro do seu adapter e depois seu listview receberia esse adapter, veja como eu faria e mostre como você instanciou seu adapter. att,

Comment: Vou editar a pergunta e colocar o adapter para você ver.

Comment: Blz, a sua classe adapter recebe uma List<Produto>(no método construtor) quando ela é instanciada em outra classe, então sempre que você instancia essa classe você passa essa lista, nessa lista o método get(position) que você usará para pegar a posição clicada da lista, o que eu queria era que você me mostrasse esse código da sua classe atual : adapter = new MinhaClasseAdapter(AtualActivity.this, list); nesse exemplo a variavel list possui as informações que você precisa, pode me mostrar como você instanciou a sua classe ListaAdapter dentro da classe principal do metodo LongClick?

Comment: Cara vou colocar tudo que estou usando na edição

Comment: Bom, vocÊ deveria ter especificado que está utilizando retrofit no titulo ou pelo menos naa descrição quando você abriu esse tópico, você não havia colocado essa informação nem nas tags e por isso pensei que estivesse usando arraylist ou algo do tipo, não conheço nada sobre retrofit, o que eu pude ajudar eu ajudei, aconselho que você faça uma nova pergunta e dessa vez especifique melhor a sua situação, assim alguém mais preparado poderá te ajudar! Abraços !